# Why is checking if two passwords match in Django so complicated?

Tags: django, design-patterns

Am I doing something wrong, or is this *seriously* what the developers expect me to write every time I want to check if two fields are the same?

```
def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    if "password1" in data and "password2" in data:
        if data["password1"] != data["password2"]:
            self._errors["password2"] = self.error_class(['Passwords do not match.'])
            del data['password2']    
    return data
```

And why do I have to validate that the username is unique?

```
def clean_username(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['username']
    if User.objects.filter(username=data).exists():
        raise ValidationError('Username already taken.')
    return data
```

It's a `ModelForm`. It should already know there's a unique constraint?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

This is the only clean method you need to define to make sure 2 passwords are correct and that the username is valid.

Use the `clean_fieldname` method so that you don't need to do more work to validate the username.

```
def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

    if not password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password")
    if password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords do not match")
    return password2
```

You're absolutely right, you **dont** need to validate the username being unique, because the ModelForm knows it needs to be unique.

The problem with your code is that you are overriding the `clean()` method, which means the ModelForm isn't doing its 'real' clean().

To get the default validation, call `super(MyForm, self).clean()` or better yet don't override `clean` at all and only specify `clean_password2`.

Comment: I think this is the conclusion I eventually came to too, thanks. Forgot about this question :)

Comment: ooops, I didn't realize this was so old :D

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, are you *seriously* complaining about four lines of boiler-plate code? If it really bothers you, create a `PasswordForm` class that contains that clean logic and sublass it for your own forms as necessary.

Secondly, you *don't* have to validate unique constraints manually. As you say, the ModelForm does it for you.

**Edit after comment**

This 'weird syntax' is because checking that two password fields match is a *different flow* than the normal scheme of things. For a start, you're checking in the main `clean` method rather than the field-specific `clean_myfield`. If it had been the latter, you just raise an exception and Django does indeed remove the field data.

So no, this isn't 7 lines on every form - see my note about subclassing - and it **certainly** isn't 7 lines times multiple fields, because you don't want to do this for any other type of field.

Comment: Well something's screwing up somewhere then..because I just got a duplicate key error. I just wanted to bitch a little bit because I'm getting sick of this project :(

Comment: And it's 7 lines... of weird syntax. Why do I have to check if the data is in the dict and then delete it? Isn't that a bit of an odd design? There's already an error list, it can check that if it wants to know if there's been an error. And I should be able to just append another one, without really caring it's already got an error. And then why return data? I'm already manipulating self.cleaned_data, it doesn't really seem necessary to return anything. If they passed me in the dict, then maybe.

Comment: And it isn't even just 7 lines... it's 7 lines on every single freaking form, multiplied by several fields.

Comment: Mark: it should not be 7 lines on every form. Read Daniel's advice and create PasswordForm class where you can store this logic.

Comment: Well, it has to be in the `clean` method because I'm comparing it to another field, no? And when I say "times multiple fields" I'm not referring specifically to "check if two fields are the same" but any sort of logic that is slightly out of the norm. I'm saying validators like "check unique" and "check if equal" should be built into the framework. Anywho.. that was yesterday. I got it out of my system now. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

http://k0001.wordpress.com/2007/11/15/dual-password-field-with-django/

---

Edit: found out the way the admin form deals with the problem: http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py

```
class AdminPasswordChangeForm(forms.Form):
    """
    A form used to change the password of a user in the admin interface.
    """
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password (again)"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(AdminPasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        """
        Saves the new password.
        """
        self.user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            self.user.save()
        return self.user
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add an `else:` part for the first `if`. Currently the function returns the `data` without setting any errors even if one of the passwords are absent - is that the intended behavior?

```
else:
    self._errors["password"] = self.error_class(['One or both of the passwords not found'])
```

`if "password1" in data and "password2" in data:` This makes sure that both passwords are present. Without this line, you'll get an error in the next line where you read `data[password1]` and `data[password2]` if either of them are not present.

Next three lines compare the passwords and sets the appropriate error message - that's required, isn't it?

As they say, make things as simple as possible, not anymore.

Comment: I don't *think* that's necessary... if either password is absent, that means there's already been an error, doesn't it? I don't really need to throw a second one. And yes, this could get ridiculously simpler. How about when defining the fields, I write `password2 = PasswordField(validate=EqualTo('password1'))`? It should be able to figure out the rest.