# Password Validation error in django 1.6

Tags: python, django

Trying to create password validation for a django application, but one problem that is persisting is in my clean_password function in forms.py, when I am testing(Using the UI form in the template) and entire matching passwords, I still raise the error message "Password does not match". Any clue to what I am doing wrong?

**forms.py:**

```
#coding=utf-8
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.forms import extras
import time
from models import ProfileUser

now=time.localtime()

###### Login for users ###########
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(label=_(u"username"),max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 20,}))
    password=forms.CharField(label=_(u"password"),max_length=30,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'size': 20,}))

    class Meta:
        """docstring for Meta"""
        model = User
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'required':True}))
    username=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username','required':True}))
    password=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
    password2=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Re-Enter Password','required':True}))




    class Meta:
        """ To Specify the fields within User model from django, and to prevent abstraction"""
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'password2')


    def clean_username(self):
        users = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data["username"])
        if not users:
            return self.cleaned_data["username"]
        raise forms.ValidationError("This username already exist")

    def clean_email(self):
        emails = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data["email"])
        if not emails:
            return self.cleaned_data["email"]
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email is already registered")

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        cleaned_data = (password, password2)

        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match ")

        return cleaned_data
```

**views.py:**

```
#coding=utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login ,logout as auth_logout
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm
from models import ProfileUser


###### Login for users ###########
def login(request):
    template_var={}
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST.copy())
        if form.is_valid():
            _login(request,form.cleaned_data["username"],form.cleaned_data["password"])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))
    template_var["form"]=form
    return render_to_response("registration/login.html",template_var,context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def _login(request,username,password):
    ret = False
    user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            auth_login(request,user)
            ret=True
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, _(u'user is not active'))
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, _(u'Incorrect username or password'))
    return ret


###### Registration for users ###########
def register(request):
    template_var={}
    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=RegisterForm(request.POST.copy())
        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data["username"]
            email=form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password=form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user=User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
            user.save()
            _login(request,username,password)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("base")
    template_var["form"]=form
    return render_to_response("registration/signup.html",template_var,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Template:**

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Signup with Indieitude{% endblock title %}

{% block search %}
{% endblock search %}


{% block space %}
<div  class="space-registration"></div>
{% endblock space %}

{% block signup %}  
<div id="content"> 
    <div class="block">
        <div class="box-login">
            <div class="head">
                 <h2 class="heading-title">Start Discovering</h2>

                <p align="center"><em>Log in with your Facebook</em>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="socialconnect"> <a href="#" class="facebook">Log in with Facebook</a>

            </div>
            <p align="center"><em>Or signup with your email & name</em>
            </p>
            <div class="box-form">
                <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}


                    <p>
                        {{form.email}}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{form.username}}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{form.password}}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{form.password2}}
                    </p>
                    <div class="alerts errorlist">
                        <span>{{form.username.errors}}</span>
                        <span>{{form.email.errors}}</span>  
                        <span>{{form.password.errors}}</span>   
                    </div>
                    <p class="agree">By signing up, I agree to Indieitude's <a href="#">Terms of Service</a> & <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register" class="button large bold">
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                 <h2 class="heading-title" align="center">Already have an account? <a href="{% url "profiles.views.login" %}">Login</a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock signup %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used a post from awhile ago here: [Why is checking if two passwords match in Django so complicated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226197/why-is-checking-if-two-passwords-match-in-django-so-complicated)

Basically, I needed to write an extra check for password2, not override the clean method django has but to extend my password2 functionality and just return passowrd2 within my function definition, and updated the error message in my template as so: {{form.password2.errors}}

Answer (score 1):

As you are validating fields that depend on one another, you should use the *clean* method. This way the cleaned_data dictionary will be already populated and you are free to perform any additional checks.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

```py
def clean_username(self):
    # ...

def clean_email(self):
    # ...

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegisterForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")

    if password != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match")
```

Comment: Still doesnt work, even when using the django clean method, any suggestions with the current code I have to remodel?

Comment: you have to make sure to get the full cleaned_data dictionary from the super(), like done in the documentation. You can leave the clean_username and clean_email methods, but remove the clean_password one and move the checks to the new clean()