# Change default django error messages for AuthenticationForm

Tags: django

I currently use this alternative `AuthenticationForm`:

```
class AuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="members")

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        pass

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'].error_messages = {'incomplete': 'Please enter a valid password.'}

        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.error_messages = {'required':'T {fieldname} is required'.format(
            fieldname=field.label)}
```

Some of this code is useless, but I'm trying to change the error message for when the user enters an incorrect password. Currently, django supplies the error message: `Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.`, though I would like it to be `Please enter the correct password`.

This is an edge case, I suppose.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to put the validation in another clean method instead of __init__ 
This pretty much walks you through it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226197/why-is-checking-if-two-passwords-match-in-django-so-complicated

Comment: According to OWASP best practices you're not supposed to give any indication whether the user filled a wrong username or password: [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet#Authentication_and_Error_Messages].

Answer (score 1):

can you try it?

```
class AuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="members")
    password = forms.CharField(error_messages={'incomplete': 'Please enter a valid password.'})
```

Comment: This didn't change the error message when an incorrect password was entered. Seems like it should!

Comment: if you want to try using "Validation Error".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445801/django-change-field-validation-message

Answer (score 0):

go to the AuthenticationForm class then edit the error_messages...

---THIS IS THE IMAGE---
[AuthenticationForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STwIo.png)
---THIS IS THE IMAGE---