# Overriding Django Default Authentication Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to override the canned error message for the Django AuthorizationForm.  Instead of it saying this field is required I am trying to get it to say Username is required.

I have tried to subclass the AuthorizationForm with the standard LoginView and it doesn't pick up my custom clean method.  I looked at this SO similar issue, [Change default django error messages for AuthenticationForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936152/change-default-django-error-messages-for-authenticationform) and tried to follow the tips in there but still can't get it to work.  Thanks in advance for any tips on what I might be doing wrong.

```
class AuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AuthenticationForm, self).clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            pass
        else:
            self.add_error('username','Username and Password required.')
            pass
```

I am trying to get it to show Username and Password Required instead of the canned default This field is required messages.  No matter what I do I can't seem to get it to pick up my code above.  I have it stored in my project forms.py file.  I believe I'm subclassing it incorrectly.  I've tried a lot of different combinations but can't seem to get it see this form.  I'm running Django 1.11

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384891/django-models-forms-replace-this-field-is-required-message#answer-5384989) answer will help you. Just see the lines inside __init__ method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jagjeet Singh Thank you!

Jagleet's suggestion helped me understand that I needed to define this form in the format below in my forms.py file for User to get my desired end result.

```
class AuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.error_messages = {'required':'{fieldname} is required'.format(
            fieldname=field.label)}
```